# Random Number from Array C

Tags: c, random

I am trying to generate a random in the range of the array size, and print the random element from the array then return the index of
such element. This is what I have so far. The code isn't working. Can anybody please help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

srand ( time(NULL) );
int myArray[11] = { 4,8,2,5,9,1,7,10,43,23,3 };
int randomIndex = rand();
int randomValue = myArray[randomIndex];
printf("Reference: %d\n", randomValue);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? An unexpected result?

Comment: this is the error: syntax error near unexpected token `time'

Comment: `rand() % 11` ?

Comment: you're going to want to change that to `int randomIndex = rand() % 11;`. `rand()` returns a value between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, which is most certainly going to be larger than 11. `myArray` indexed at anything greater than 10 is undefined behavior.

Comment: Do you have a `main` function?

Comment: @SarahB the code won't compile as you lack `;` in the line that generates the index. What's more you updated the question to include what appears to be the answer. I would suggest accepting one of the answers (if they meet your requirements) and move on.

Comment: @orhtej2 well it still doesn't compile..thank you for catching that!

Comment: Rolled back. You must not change the question once you have answers leaving them without context! A good C book would be a helpful reading.

Comment: It is extremely annoying when questions are edited in such a manner as to invalidate existing answers.  It's essentially vandalism:(

Comment: What specifically is unclear about the last two comments? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298799/4774918

Comment: well it still doesn't run..and I apologize about that..I am not that familiar with SO..won't do that in the future.

Comment: yes, i have a main function @Mureinik

Comment: 'well it still doesn't run' is not useful.  Look, make a MCVE by enclosing the code in a valid main() function or by calling a fuction enclosing the above code from main()., fix the out-of-bounds addressing, compile, link, test what you then have and, if there is still an issue, please ask another question.

Comment: How about getting a [good C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) - get one for modern C, i.e. C99 at leat, best standard C11) and learn the language properly from the beginning. Requiring at least `int main(void)` (`int main()` is a legacy and obsolescent) is shown with the very first program you learn. Obscure youtube videos, blogs or online tutorials are not appropriate. And we are not a tutoring site.

Comment: @Olaf It had that in there. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems that your code is outside a function, so wrap it by, for example, function `main`.

Second, function `rand` returns a pseudo-random integer value between ​0​ and `RAND_MAX`, which is usually a value much higher than your array size `11`.
Hence, you have a very good chance to exceed array bounds.

Limit the `randomIndex` to `11`, e.g. by using modulo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int myArray[11] = { 4,8,2,5,9,1,7,10,43,23,3 };
    int randomIndex = rand() % 11;
    int randomValue = myArray[randomIndex];
    printf("Reference: %d\n", randomValue);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that modulo (i.e. `%11`) is a very simple method to cap the number, and it yields a non-uniform distribution of random values. If this gets a problem, please do not hesitate to ask again.

Comment: My concern regarding everyone suggesting modulo is it's a terrible practice that produces a non-uniform distribution.

Comment: @orhtej2: right in general, but I think it is OK when answering a beginner's question. Added a comment.

Comment: @usr my point is there are better and not that complicated ways of capping the range.

Answer (score -1):

[`rand()` generates a value between 0 and RAND_MAX](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/), you should cap it to array length i.e. like [here](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)

```
const int N = 11; // length of myArray
int randomIndex = rand() / (RAND_MAX / N + 1);
```

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   srand ( time(NULL) );
    int myArray[11] = { 4,8,2,5,9,1,7,10,43,23,3 };
  const int N = 11; // lenght of myArray
 int randomIndex = rand() / (RAND_MAX / N + 1)
    printf("Reference: %d\n", randomValue);
 return 0; 
}

Comment: @SarahB seems reasonable, does it work as expected?

Comment: no, it doesn't. I edited the code in the original question. Not sure why its showing this now..
line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 4: `int main()'

Comment: @SarahB Yes, there's a semicolon missing.

Comment: `rand() / (RAND_MAX / N + 1)` does not distribute `rand()` that evenly in that `randomIndex` comes up `10`  less often than `0`-`9`  (maybe 10 less in about 200,000,000).  `rand() %11` is a flatter distribution. IAC a fair distribution is more work.

Comment: @orhtej2 no there is no semicolon missing..its the main

Comment: @chux I fail to see that. That's one bucket skewed (if any) vs `RAND_MAX % 11` buckets favoured. Can you please explain?

Comment: @orhtej2 "That's one bucket skewed" is not so with this method.  With `rand()%M` (M==11) the eleven buckets, some buckets will have `N` and others will have `N+1` occurrences.  With this approach, example `(RAND_MAX + 1 == 2**31)`: The first ten numbers will occur `P` times each and the eleventh will have `P-9`occurrences. More unbalanced.  This answer's approach has merit with FP math, yet with `int` math, I see it as weaker than  `rand()%11` given the last number (worst case) could occur about M less than the others.